# GraphQL SpringBoot Security Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to GraphQL and am trying to run it with SpringBoot security. For some reason when I enable @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) in the config class I start getting exception when I boot my application as:

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No node
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:132)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:61)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:33)
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:52)
    at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:43)
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory.createPreInvocationAttribute(ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource.java:73)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor$MethodSecurityMetadataSourcePointcut.matches(MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:252)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:289)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:321)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:126)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:347)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Can someone please let me know where could I be going wrong? Or if I am missing on anything.
My security config class looks as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    //Logic...
  }
}
```

Also adding here the main application class with all the annotations:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
    ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
    SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
    SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class,
    UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
//Logic
}
```

Comment: Can you share any Pre/Post annotations you have in your application?

Comment: I have not configured the Pre/Post annotations which are specific to the security. I was before I added these annotations I started having issues. I have been following this article for the setup:https://michalgebauer.github.io/spring-graphql-security/

Comment: It looks like the error is caused by a SpEL expression. Could you share any SpEL expressions in your application? They may be in the method `configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)`

Comment: Hi, Apologies for the late reply. I am not using any SpEL in the code. However, I was able to get a workaround solution which works pretty well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The error-message is a bit unclear, but with the hints from comments, I was able to locate the error.

It was indeed a `SpEL`-error, which was not noticed by IntelliJ nor the compiler.
I had an empty `PostAuthorize`-expression

```java
@RestController
public class FileController {

    @PostMapping
    @PostAuthorize("")   //<- this causing the error
    public ResponseEntity<Void> uploadInvoiceFile(
            @RequestParam("file") final MultipartFile uploadedFile) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The beginning of the stacktrace helps to locate the error. The "bad class" was mentioned:

```java
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileController' defined in file [PATH_TO_BAD_CLASS]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No node
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:617)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
```